# Mahout's recommenditembased returns already existing item

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I have used mahout's (v 0.9) recommenditembased with arguments

> --input /usr_pref.csv --numRecommendations 10 --output /out/ --tempDir /temp1/ --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION

On checking the result I found out that it recommended for a user an item that he had already rated. Why did something like this happen?

Thank you for your time.

As requested here is a snippet of the recommendations:

> 34175 [89005462:1.7624004,89017464:0.11477072,89011967:0.11375865,89007606:0.113421306,14103126:0.11096669,89002502:0.10888276,14103124:0.106607914,89011035:0.10636083,40111014:0.104254685,89016109:0.104254685]

and the corresponding line from user preferences:

> 34175,89005462,0.07596562

I have upload the two files in dropbox.
recommendations: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uapzq0926y7427p/outusrpref_final
user preferences: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nru9799udgrzl8/usr_pref_final.csv

UPDATE
Acting on the idea that my problem had to do with the range of my ratings I multiplied them by 100 and then truncated them to two demical digits. After running the recommendator I found no duplicates. Still I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Unless you've found a bug this wont happen. Mahout is only now (in Mahout 1.0-SNAPSHOT) adding a flag to allow returning items the user has shown a preference for. Can you show a snippet of the preference data and recommender output?  Are you sure the user IDs match?

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Apache Mahout is Recommending an Item that the user has Already rated?

There may be a chance that you are not updating that users ratings for the item in file which you are giving it as input to mahout.

For Example:
If you are giving input.csv as input to the mahout kindly check whether you have updated the input.csv. (i.e) check whether the input.csv file contains the user id with that ratings.
Mahout will not recommend an item that is already been rated and updated in you input file.

Solution:

Try to update your input file with the user who has already and then check. This may fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you propose. My users ratings do not change during my test. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Kindly find whether my second answer below is clear to you and helps you.

Comment: Hey, I'm running into this very same problem at the moment. Wouldn't happen to have found the reason for this, would you?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Unfortunatelly I have not found a solution. The only workaround is what I said in my update. I have multiplied my ratings by 100 because they were too small. As long as I can see my problem has gone away. Still it is weird and casts a shadow of doubt on the overal performance of the system.

Comment: I switched over to using parallelALS as per the factorize-movielens.sh example and this problem disappeared. Produced better results too.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

now,check your input file which your going to feed as input to mahout

Example: input.csv

```
979    300    2.0

979    400    1.0

800    200    3.0

800    300    4.0
```

Recommendations.csv (In this case userid 979,itemid 200,ratings 1.0)

```
979 [200:1.0]

800 [400:2.0]
```

**Note:**
Mahout will recommend only item 200 for userid 979 and will not recommend item 300 and 400 since it is already been rated and stored in input.csv and which is going to be feed as input to mahout.

like wise open your two files and cross check once manually. I guess Mahout recommendation will not recommend for the item which is already been rated.

Suggestion:
For testing create a small set of input data and test it so that it would be easy to track and identify.